# Watermarking TIFF with pillow in Python breaks georeferencing

Tags: geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to automate the watermarking of thousands of georeferenced TIFF files with a Python script. The files have related tfwx world files and aux.xml files. When I run the code the spatial referencing seems to be corrupted. The cell size of the output TIFF seems to be 200x larger. I can then run arcpy.Rescale_management to recover their proper size, but they are still incorrectly placed.

Here is a stripped down version of the code I am using:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os, sys, arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r'D:\mbrush\scratch\tools\CalTrans\testing'
workspace = env.workspace
env.overwriteOutput = True

# copywrite logo and name
text = u'\u00a9' + ' Company Name'

# iterate through tiffs and watermark
for file in os.listdir(workspace):
    if file.endswith('.tif'):

        # open image
        im = Image.open(workspace + '\\' + file)

        # open image for drawing
        drawing = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

        # determine height and width of image
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]

        # determine where to place the text
        posx = width - (500)
        posy = height - (80)
        pos = (posx, posy)

        # set font size
        fontsize = 33

        # define outfile to overwrite original
        img_out = workspace + '\\' + file

        # choose font
        font = ImageFont.truetype(r'C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial/arial.ttf', fontsize)

        # create text shadow
        shadow = (pos[0]-1, pos[1]-1)
        shadow2 = (pos[0]-2, pos[1]-2)
        shadow3 = (pos[0]+1, pos[1]+1)
        shadow4 = (pos[0]+2, pos[1]+2)
        drawing.text(shadow, text, fill=(200,200,200), font=font)
        drawing.text(shadow2, text, fill=(255,255,255), font=font)
        drawing.text(shadow3, text, fill=(200,200,200), font=font)
        drawing.text(shadow4, text, fill=(255,255,255), font=font)

        # draw watermark
        drawing.text(pos, text, fill=(3, 8, 12), font=font)

        # save image
        im.save(img_out)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recover the spatial referencing of the original georefernced tif using gdal translate.

```
import gdal, osr

original = gdal.Open('path to tif')        # the original georeferenced tif
in_tif = 'path to watermarked tif'          # the one that lost spatial reference
out_tif = 'path to tif to be created'       # the georeferenced output tif

rf = original.GetSpatialRef()
gcps = original.GetGCPs()
gdal.Translate(str(out_tif), in_tif, format='GTiff', GCPs=gcps, outputSRS=rf)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use gdal/ogr to georeference your output rasters using the metadata from the input rasters.

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

src_tif = gdal.Open('input.tif')
new_tif = gdal.Open('output.tif')

ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = src_tif.GetGeoTransform()
lrx = ulx + (src_tif.RasterXSize * xres)
lry = uly + (src_tif.RasterYSize * yres)


gdal.Translate('georeferenced_input.tif', new_tif, outputBounds=[ulx,uly,lrx,lry])
```